# Is there a known issue with the Google Drive API and permissions?

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I'm creating a new document and share it to everyone but the document can't be edited by anyone unless I manually go back in the document and share it again. I'm using this library : https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. Note that when I go see the document on the drive, it says it share to anyone and that they can edit but that's not the case:

```
private function make_file($service, $name, $content, $parent_id) {

    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parent_id);

    $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $permission->setType('anyone');
    $permission->setRole('writer');
    $permission->setWithLink(true);
    $permission->setValue(null);

    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setTitle($name);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
    $new_file = $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => 'text/html',
            'uploadType' => 'media',
            'convert' => true
        )
    );

    $service->permissions->insert($new_file->getId(), $permission);

    return $new_file;

}
```

Comment: When some try to open and edit the shared file, what error do they get?

Comment: _translated from French_

'Authorization is required'

You have to ask the access to the owner or connect with an account that has the proper authorization.